# ViewModels are not disposed in MvvmCross - how to manage subscriptions?

Tags: c#, android, windows-phone, xamarin, mvvmcross

Let's consider a simple application that consists of two views and two view models.

There is a button on FirstView which fires ShowViewModel and a button on SecondView which fires ShowViewModel.

Let's say that FirstViewModel also subscribes to messages of type MyMessage in the ctor.

Scenario: the user starts application, presses button on FirstView and than on SecondView. Now we have the following back stack: FirstView->SecondView->FirstView. Since ShowViewModel always creates a new instance we actually have TWO FirstViewModel objects in memory. Each of them is subscribed to MyMessages!

What can I do to avoid this? I want to make sure that only one instance of each ViewModel class is subscribed at the same time. Do I have to use platform dependent handlers in Views (like OnNavigatedTo/OnNavigatedFrom) to avoid this? Or is there a cross platform way?

Comment: Is this covered by N=42 in http://mvvmcross.blogspot.co.uk/

Comment: I'll try to have a look today, thank you Stuart

Comment: That's a good tutorial Stuart, but for now I think that the best way to go is to rework navigation in the app to avoid "loops" in navigation.